# replace array object at perticular index in setState

Tags: reactjs

I have an update button which gets me the updated object and I have the index at which I want to replace the array with this object:

```
updateVal = () => {
  console.log("this.state::", this.state);
  let alleditvals = {
    username: this.state.uname_edit,
    password: this.state.pass_edit,
    address: this.state.address_edit
  };
  console.log("w::", this.state.add_data[this.state.count_edit]);
  console.log("alleditvals::", alleditvals);
  console.log("this.state.add_data[1]", this.state.add_data[1]);

  this.state.add_data.map((a, i) => {
    console.log("i::", i);
    console.log("a::", a);

    if (this.state.count_edit == i) {
      console.log(this.state.add_data[i]);
    }
  });
}
```

the state is like this:

```
this.state = {
  uname: "",
  pass: "",
  address: "",
  salary: "",

  add_data: [],

  edit_obj: {},
  edit_showui: false,

  uname_edit: "",
  pass_edit: "",
  address_edit: "",
  count_edit: null,
  changed_after_edit: {},

  errorfields: {
    uname_err: "",
    pass_err: "",
    address_err: "",
    salary_err: "",
    valid_user: false,
    valid_pass: false,
    valid_address: false,
    valid_salary: false
  }
};
```

so my array is `add_data` which i want to replace with `alleditvals` at index `this.state.count_edit`. I have also checked on map function that if the index of current count matched the `add_data` index, please replace it, but don't know how to replace it.

```
if(this.state.count_edit == i){
  console.log(this.state.add_data[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your component state with the `setState` method, and use the array method `map` on your `add_data` array and replace the element at index `count_edit` with the `alleditvals` object.

```
updateVal = () => {
  let alleditvals = {
    username: this.state.uname_edit,
    password: this.state.pass_edit,
    address: this.state.address_edit
  };

  this.setState(({ count_edit, add_data }) => ({
    add_data: add_data.map((item, index) =>
      index === count_edit ? alleditvals : item
    )
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `setState`, you can update state easily.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      allData: [],
      index: 0
    }
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.state.allData.push({ name1: "Test1", name2: "Test2"}); 
  }

  push1 = () =>
  {
    this.setState({
      index: 1
    })
  }

  push2 = () =>
  {
    this.setState({
      index: 2
    })
  }

  render() {
    const list = this.state.allData.map((value, index) => {                                             
      return (
        <div>
        { this.state.index === 1? value.name1 : value.name2 }
        </div>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.push1}>Push 1</button><br/><br/>
      <button onClick={this.push2}>Push 2</button><br/><br/>
      <div>
        {list}
      </div>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

In this example I pressed Push2 = Test2 shows. If you press Push1, Test1 will appear.

[image]